# Is alloca part of the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, alloca

Is alloca part of the C++ standard?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. The answer says it all.

Answer (score 24):

Not only is it not part of the C++ standard, it is not part of *any* standard. It's not part of C nor is it part of POSIX. Furthermore, allow me to quote from the Linux man page for `alloca(3)`:

> The  alloca()  function is machine and
>   compiler dependent. On many systems
>   its implementation is buggy. **Its use
>   is discouraged**.

(emphasis added)

Comment: What about embedded systems??

Comment: Is there something equivalent to `alloca` (i.e. something that allocates a dynamic amount of memory on the stack) that **is** part of the C standard?

Comment: @mercury0114 There is C99's variable length arrays that do something a bit similar, although the scope of the allocation is not the same as with `alloca`.