# Why can not alloca be used in function argument list?

Tags: c, stack, allocation, alloca

Quoting the second paragraph of `BUGS` section, from manpage of `alloca(3)`

> On  many  systems `alloca()` cannot be used inside the list of arguments of a function call, because the stack
>          space reserved by `alloca()` would appear on the stack in the middle of the space for the function arguments.

I failed to see how this would happen. Taking the following code as example:

```
void f(int a, void * b, int c);

int
main(void)
{
    f(1, alloca(100), 2);
}
```

Based on my understanding, `alloca` expands the stack frame for `main` down 100 bytes (by modifying stack pointer register), then the pointer to that block of stack memory (along with 2 `int`s) is passed on stack frame for `f`. So the allocated space shouldn't be in the middle of `a`, `b` or `c`, actually it should be on a different frame (which is on frame for `main` in this case).

So what's the misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note right away that [`alloca` is *not standard*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318306/is-alloca-part-of-the-c-standard). It is an extension to platforms that wanted to give even more ways for programmers to hang themselves by potentially dynamically consuming automatic variable space in the interest of speed over slow dynamic memory allocators based on other techniques (heaps, etc). (yes, my opinion, but there's much truth within).

That said, consider this:

Have you ever written a compiler before? [There is no standard guarantee of evaluation order of function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/367663/1322972). So just suppose some platform chose to build the [activation record](http://wiki.c2.com/?ActivationRecord) for a call to `f` by ultimately pushing the following into the activation stack, from right to left (their choice):

1. Pushes 2 into the activation record stack space.
2. Performs `alloca(100)`, which sucks down *the same stack* holding the call activation record being built by an additional 100 `char`.
3. Pushes the result of (2), a `void*`, into the activation record stack space.
4. Pushes 1 into the activation record stack space.
5. Invokes `call f` which, pushes the return address in `main` into the activation record stack space.

Now, think of yourself as the function `f`. Where do you expect to find the third parameter to your function? Um....

That is just one example of how one can toss `alloca` space somewhere that can cause problems.

Comment: Does `third parameter` point to `1` or `2`? Why inside the function `f` we can't find third parameter? Could you explain it in more detail? because the compiler don't know about how many memory allocated by `alloca` is being occupied?

Comment: @rosshjb compile the function (not the call, the actual function) to asm. It will show where the arguments are expected to reside. Note that this can change considerably from toolchain to toolchain, and optimization levels, so try several ways.  Ex: assuming 32bit cdecl, the function expects to find `c` at [sp+12], `b` at [sp+8], `a` at [sp+4], and the return address at [sp].  Problem: using `alloca` for `b` would leave a huge unexpected (and undetectable) hole between `c` and `b`.